# Arguments and Command Prompt

Tags: vb.net, command-line

So, What I'm trying to do is make command prompt open on button press with set perimeters. This is what I have so far:

```
Public ReadOnly Property TheIP() As String
    Get

        Return TextBox1.Text

    End Get
End Property
```

---

```
Process.Start("cmd", String.Format("/k {0} & {1} & {2}", "ping", TheIP, "-t", "-l"))
```

---

The problem I am having is "ping" and "-t" isn't getting executed properly.

I get the following message in command prompt:

```
'123.123.123.123' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

I also get

```
'-t' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Answer (score 2):

What are the `&` doing in the string? That's a command prompt command to launch a new process.

e.g. `dir & dir` will run `dir` twice. So your string is running ping and then trying to run the IP as a command by itself.

Try:

```
Process.Start("cmd", String.Format("/k {0} {1} {2}", "ping", TheIP, "-t"))
```

(I took "-l" out because you don't have enough string formatting places to use it, and it needs parameters itself, anyway)

Or

```
Process.Start("cmd", String.Format("/k ping -t {0}", TheIP))
```

Comment: That works but the thing is I absolutely need the -l in the script.

Comment: but if you put `-l` in, it just gives `Value must be supplied for option -l`. If you have a value to give it, just put that in the string as well, e.g. `"/k ping -l 1000 -t {0}"`